# Is it safe to use calphalon when the aanondized coating begins to wear?

Tags: aluminum-cookware

Is it safe to use calphalon if the anodized coating is beginning to wear?

Comment: I have been always wary of cooking on anything that has begun to chip, scratch or wear as the coating usually ends up on your food; and finally inside you. So I (personally) would be ready to flip the cookware to the bin.

Comment: The short answer is maybe.  If it is peeling or chipping, then there is an additional non-stick coating over the anodized aluminum, which could be harmful.  Hard anodized aluminum tends to be difficult to scratch or wear (compared to other finishes), and does not peel off.

Comment: It is not nonstick so it isn't chipping or peeling.  I've had this many years.  The darker hard anodized coating is beginning to wear thin in a few places allowing a lighter metal to show through ever so slightly.  I've heard concerns regarding aluminum and Alzheimer's which is the source of my concern.

Comment: @mentortchr - Health questions are outside the purview of this site.  For what it's worth, bare aluminum is still widely used in food preparation (especially on commercial scales), and even if you have a few spots of bare aluminum in your pan, it's unlikely this will increase your aluminum intake significantly.  Many processed foods contain more aluminum than you'd get by cooking most foods in a bare  aluminum pot (let alone one that is mostly anodized).